# cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I've problem with Guzzle HTTP client,
when i send `post` request manually (using postman) to `oauth/token`, i get the token and refresh token correctly but when i request sent using guzzle, it freezes and do not get any response for a while, after timeout return exception bottom

```
    "message": "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)",
    "exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\SMART\\Desktop\\shopkit-backend\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
    "line": 200,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\SMART\\Desktop\\shopkit-backend\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
            "line": 155,
            "function": "createRejection",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\SMART\\Desktop\\shopkit-backend\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlFactory.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "finishError",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\SMART\\Desktop\\shopkit-backend\\vendor\\guzzlehttp\\guzzle\\src\\Handler\\CurlHandler.php",
            "line": 43,
            "function": "finish",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\CurlFactory",
            "type": "::"
....
```

this is my code

```
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'timeout' => 10
        ]); //GuzzleHttp\Client
        try {
            $result = $client->post(url('oauth/token'), [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => $this->_client_id,
                    'client_secret' => $this->_client_secret,
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'password' => $req->password,
//                'scope' => $scopes
                ]
            ]);
        } catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
            $response = json_encode((string)$e->getResponse()->getBody());
        }
```

what should i do?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or the code that you post with postman?

Comment: Why are you using curl to get data from your own code?

Comment: If you're using Laravel Passport, you're doing it wrong, no need to send a curl request to get token from your own app.

Comment: @HafezDivandari yes, it's laravel code, i need to user can login using username, email and phone number, in order to i wrote a function to verify input params, then try to get token, what do u think about it?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze, Guzzle uses curl to send request, and laravel passport uses Guzzle

Comment: I am convinced stackoverflow has become the most useless place to obtain useful answers, I cannot ask the same question due to duplication and shit

Answer (score 0):

Check for your firewall if it's active and disable it

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw disable
```